# Strangeness with dynamic arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory, dynamic

I am honestly not quite sure what is going on here.
It has been years since I have programmed in C++, but I am trying to execute this code

```
short* result = new short[3];
```

now, I would expect that this creates an array with 3 memory locations: 0,1 and 2, but for what ever reason, this works:

```
result[0] = someObject::parseShort();
```

but this does not work:

```
result[1] = someObject::parseShort();
```

no exception is thrown, but it is like addresses 1 and 2 dont even exist? I have verified this with visual studio's debugger, and this is leading to some very interesting results when I try to read from those memory addresses, no matter what I Initially wrote to them, they always seem to return 0
Like I said, its been years since I've written anything in C++, and would appreciate someone being able to tel me what is going on? because as far as I can tell, it looks like I am defining the array right?

EDIT:
here is the rest of the relevent code:

```
phoneNumber::phoneNumber(string number)
{
    short* nbrs = parseNumber(number);
    areaCode = nbrs[0];
    prefix = nbrs[1];
    this->number = nbrs[2];
    delete[] nbrs;
}
```

areaCode, prefix, and number are all members of the class.
area code gets set correctly, but prefix and number dont seem to

here is the definition of parseNumber:

```
short* phoneNumber::parseNumber(string num)
{
    if (num == "")
        throw new exception("value should not be null");
    int var= 3;
    short* result= new short[var];
    string temp = "";
    bool fail = false;
    int j = 0;
    bool ready = false;

    num = Utils::removeSpaces(num);
            if (j ==0&&num[0] != '(')
        {

            fail = true;



        }
    for (int i = 1; i < num.length(); i++)
    {

        if (fail)
        {
            throw exception("Could not parse phone number! Invalid format, expected (xxx)xxx-xxxx");
        }

        if (num[i] >= '0' && num[i] <= '9')
        {
            temp+=num[i];
            continue;
        }
        else if (j== 0 && num[i] ==')')
        {
            if(temp.length() != 3)
            {
                fail = true;
                continue;
            }
            ready = true;
        }
        else if(j==1 && num[i] =='-')
        {

            if(temp.length() != 3)
            {
                fail = true;
                continue;
            }
            ready = true;

        }
        else if (j == 3 && i == num.length() -1)
        {
            if(temp.length() != 4)
            {
                fail = true;
                continue;
            }
            ready = true;
        }
        else
        {
            fail = true;
            continue;
        }
        if (ready)
        {
            result[j]= Utils::parseShort(temp);
            j++;
            temp = "";
            ready = false;
            continue;

        }else
        {
            temp+= num[i];
        }


    }
    if (temp.length()==4)
        result[j]= Utils::parseShort(temp);
    else
    {
        throw exception("Could not parse phone number! Invalid format, expected (xxx)xxx-xxxx");
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Your code (as you've shown it) is fine, but the debugger has no way of knowing that the pointer-to-short `result` is pointing to an array (and not just a single `short`), so it displays only the first item by default. You can force all three to be displayed by typing in `result,3` in the Watch window. Some other part of your code must contain the bug -- can you post a short example that doesn't work as you expect?

Comment: "This does not work"...

Comment: Don't use built in arrays, pointers or `new`. Use `std::vector` or `std::array`.

Comment: @Cameron: Alternative Watch window syntax is `result,[3]`. It actually works even with non-constant (run-time) values between the `[]`. In fact, I believe the `,[n]` form is actually the official syntax now.

Comment: @Cameron: I know that it works with a naked `3`. I'm just pointing out that there's an *alternative* syntax with more expansive functionality.

Comment: Do some debugging to check that you are actually setting the right fields for `result[j]`. Perhaps `j` is not what you think it is, or you access out of bounds.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I set breakpoints and have verified that the program is coming up with the right 3 answers with different inputs, and have als verified that the parseShort function is giving the right answer too, but it just does not seem to be working right? J also appears to be at the correct index. At this point, I am probably going to try a different algorithm all together. Looking back at my code all these hours later, it still looks valid to me, but I am not sure why I wrote it the way I did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are defining your array right. You have a bug elsewhere in your code outside the part that constitutes your question.